# Spring Boot: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'. Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; Could not instantiate entity due to: null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am unable to startup a simple CRUD application with Spring Boot Hibernate due to the below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate entity 'com.sij.demospringboot.entities.StudentEntity' due to: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at .....
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate entity 'com.sij.demospringboot.entities.StudentEntity' due to: null
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at ...
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    javax.annotation.Generated cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.annotation.Generated cannot be resolved to a type

    at com.sij.demospringboot.entities.StudentEntity.<init>(StudentEntity.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

My StudentityEntitycode is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentEntity  implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotEmpty(message="Name is mandatory")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(nullable = true, name = "email")
    private String email;

}
```

My application.properties is given below

```
server.port = 8082

# JPA/Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# H2 Database
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:dcbapp
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

What is going `null` which is stopping the bean from being created?

Comment: please show the entire stacktrace, you've left vital parts out

Comment: Your code is not compiling.

Comment: Hi Tech de Enigma, the error is in the stacktrace: "javax.annotation.Generated cannot be resolved to a type". My guess is that you are using some @Generated without including valid libraries. The stacktrace seems to indicate the error lies in StudentEntity.java, line 22 as well

Comment: @HoàngLong  The `javax.annotation.Generated` is caused when adding lombok annotations. Even though there is this error, the getters and setters are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. The lombok version used in the pom.xml mismatched the lombok used for installing the IDE. I used the same version for configuring Eclipse and for the project and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> What is going `null` which is stopping the bean from being created?

The top part of a stacktrace error message is in this case about a follow up error. It says only that Hibernate can't instantiate the entity using its constructor.

The real cause of the error is shown in the bottom part of the stacktrace. Your entity class doesn't even compile! The compile error is most probably in an import statement (not shown in your post). Something like

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
```

To fix this error you can try to remove all not used import statements.

Comment: The `javax.annotation.Generated` is caused when adding lombok annotations. Even though there is this error, the getters and setters are working.